# How to install CocoaAsyncSocket library into Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

There are a lot of information on how to use GCDAsyncSockets with Objective-C but so few with Swift, and almost no information on how to actually install it into the Xcode environment. I tried adding files in the zip file one at a time with File | Add Files to ... Project menu option but still I cannot use the added files with "import GCDAsyncUdpSocket" statement. It says "No such module". There's gotta be an easier way of doing this, right?

Comment: [cocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/)

Answer (score 0):

**Install using CocoaPods by adding this line to your Podfile:**

`use_frameworks!` *# Add this if you are targeting iOS 8+ or using Swift*

```
pod 'CocoaAsyncSocket'
```

CocoaAsyncSocket is Carthage compatible. To include it add the following line to your Cartfile

```
Carthage/Build/iOS/CocoaAsyncSocket.framework
Carthage/Build/tvOS/CocoaAsyncSocket.framework
Carthage/Build/Mac/CocoaAsyncSocket.framework
```

Select the correct framework(s) and drag it into your project.

**Manual**

You can also include it into your project by adding the source files directly, but you should probably be using a dependency manager to keep up to date.

**Importing**

Using Objective-C:

`@import CocoaAsyncSocket;` When using iOS 8+ frameworks

or 
                                                                    `#import "CocoaAsyncSocket.h"`  When not using frameworks, targeting iOS 7 or below

Using Swift:

```
import CocoaAsyncSocket
```

Comment: This is from their readme file. But I don't have CocoaPods. And installing CocoaPods will probably be harder than installing CocoaAsyncSocket. My question was there's gotta be a better way doing this "in Apple way". Also, the Manual method doesn't really help here. Instead of that little paragraph they could've just said "We didn't work with this in Swift, so you just figure it out how to install it on Swift", which is exactly what I had to go thru. But still, I could only install GCDAsyncUdpSocket file, not the whole thing. So my question still stands, there's gotta be a better way of doingit

Comment: These are the type of things that you actually have to sit through and take 5 minutes of life to read, the instructions are very straight forward, just got to be patient and read.@BrianHawk

Answer (score 0):

***I following this steps successful use the AsyncSocket class by CocoaAsyncSocket***

1. copy CocoaAsyncSocket project source on github
2. click **CocoaAsyncSocket.xcodeproj** file open CocoaAsyncSocket project
3. copy  iOS version **AsyncSocket.m AsyncSocket.h AsyncUdpSocket.m AsyncUdpSocket.h** file to  your use CocoaAsyncSocket project
4. xcode will tell you create a Bridging-head file，create it
5. edit the **xxx-Bridging-head.h**（xxx is your project name）file add `#import "AsyncSocket.h"`